# How to get the Outlook add-in in the calendar view

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

I am aware of the AppointmentOrganizerCommandSurface extension points which will display the add-in  if I try to create a new meeting from the Home tab --> New Meeting/Appointment.

Is there any extension point that can be used so that the add-in will be available if I click on calendar view ? [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently this feature is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [user-voice page](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins). Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process.

[Outlook Add-ins Engineering Team]